# Spring MVC - how to update row in database using JSP table?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I got problem with update entered values in jsp table, I don't know where I should put `form action` and `c:forEach` in order to everything will be comaptible. Where is the problem?

In this case entered values receives `null`, and after click "edit" every row is being empty:

```
<div class="forms">
    <div class="selectr">
    <p style="font-size: 13"> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr style="font-size: 13">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Salary</td>
            <td>Phone number</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr style="font-size: 10">
                <td><input disabled style="width: 17px" type="text" name="id" value="${employee.id}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="name" value="${employee.name}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="lastName" value="${employee.lastName}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 60px"  type="text" name="gender" value="${employee.gender}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 80px" type="text" name="position" value="${employee.position}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 60px" type="text" name="salary" value="${employee.salary}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 100px" type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${employee.phoneNumber}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 160px" type="text" name="address" value="${employee.address}"></td>
                <td><form action="/VirtualClinic/employeelist.html?editEmployee=${employee.id}"  method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Edit"/></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </div>
```

In this case entered values is not null (I check it with `System.out.println(employee.getName()` but still they dont want to be updated, because after click updated value get back to default value from database):

```
 <form action="/VirtualClinic/employeelist.html?editEmployee="   method="POST">
 <div class="forms">
    <div class="selectr">
    <p style="font-size: 13"> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr style="font-size: 13">
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First name</td>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Salary</td>
            <td>Phone number</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr style="font-size: 10">
                <td><input disabled style="width: 17px" type="text" name="id" value="${employee.id}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="name" value="${employee.name}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 75px" type="text" name="lastName" value="${employee.lastName}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 60px"  type="text" name="gender" value="${employee.gender}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 80px" type="text" name="position" value="${employee.position}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 60px" type="text" name="salary" value="${employee.salary}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 100px" type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${employee.phoneNumber}"></td>
                <td><input style="width: 160px" type="text" name="address" value="${employee.address}"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Edit"/></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

DAO:

```
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    String query = "update virtualclinic.employee SET name=?, lastname=?, gender=?,"
            + "position=?, salary=?, phonenumber=?, address=? WHERE idemployee=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
        ps.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
        ps.setString(3, employee.getGender());
        ps.setString(4, employee.getPosition());
        ps.setString(5, employee.getSalary());
        ps.setString(6, employee.getPhoneNumber());
        ps.setString(7, employee.getAddress());
        ps.setString(8, employee.getId());

        int out = ps.executeUpdate();                    

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Service:

```
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    employeeDAO = ctx.getBean("employeeDAO", EmployeeDAOImpl.class);            

    employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);

}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeelist.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(Model model, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, @RequestParam String editEmployee) throws SQLException {

    setAppContext();

    clinicService.updateEmployee(employee);

    System.out.println(employee.getName());

    List<Employee> employees = clinicService.getAllEmployees();
    model.addAttribute("employees", employees);

    ModelAndView mstaff = new ModelAndView("EmployeeList");
    return mstaff;

}
```

Comment: Example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: Better to use Ajax instead of form action to update each row individually.
Otherwise you have to change your html design as form action is written at the end of table but form elements should be inside form tag.

Comment: use ajax to update row or create edit button which shows existing data on another page and then use single form to update data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your first JSP in project. Also I don't see your tld imports but one of the most common causes of problems with the EL and JSTL is a configuration mismatch between the version of JSP that you are using, the version of the JSTL that you employ, and how you have declared your web application in the deployment descriptor (web.xml).

For a JSP 2.1 container (such as Tomcat 6), you should be using JSTL 1.2, and you should have your web application declared as a Servlets 2.5 web app by using the Servlets 2.5 XML Schema.

For a JSP 2.0 container (such as Tomcat 5), you should be using JSTL 1.1, and you should have your web application declared as a Servlets 2.4 web app by using the Servlets 2.4 XML Schema.